# How to convert df with item ratings to df that contains number of users that rated a pair of items?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a df that contains the number of users that rated rated both movies from a pair for every pair of movies.

My original df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}, 'userID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 1, 6: 2}, 'MovieID': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2}, 'rating': {0: 4, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3}})
```

which looks like:

| index | userID | MovieID | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | 3 |

What i want to achieve

| movieID / movieID | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | nan | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | nan |

Currently I'm computing this df iteratively; for each unique combination of movieID's, and passing the ids to this function

```
def foo(id1, id2):
  id1_users = set(df[df["movieID"] == id1]["userID"].to_list())
  id2_users = set(df[df["movieID"] == id2]["userID"].to_list())
  combined = len(id1_users & id2_users)
  return combined
```

Is there a faster way to compute this?

Comment: If you aren't already aware of it  `df.pivot` could be a solution here. I just didn't figure out who to get the same data(column) als index and column of the new dataframe....maybe you get ahead with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute your table without loops, you should first generate a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `any` to identify the users that voted at least once for a movie. Then use a [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product to count the cross correlations, with eventually a [`numpy.fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) to hide the self-correlations.

```
d = df.pivot_table(index='userID',
                   columns='MovieID',
                   values='rating',
                   aggfunc=any, 
                   fill_value=False)
out = d.T.dot(d)

# optional, to remove self correlations (in place)
import numpy as np
np.fill_diagonal(out.values, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
MovieID    0    1    2
MovieID               
0        NaN    2    1
1          2  NaN    2
2          1    2  NaN
```

Intermediate pivot table:

```
MovieID  0  1  2
userID          
1        1  1  0
2        1  1  1
3        0  1  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative way to do it. Using `itertools.combinations`, we can find pairs of `MovieID`s and find the set of users who rated each pair to obtain `values` dictionary.

Then reformat this dictionary to get `out` dictionary which we cast to a DataFrame:

```
from itertools import combinations
users = df.groupby('MovieID')['userID'].apply(list).to_dict()
values = {(mov1, mov2): len(set(users[mov1]).intersection(users[mov2])) for mov1, mov2 in combinations(set(df['MovieID']), 2)}
out = {}
for (i,c), v in values.items():
    out.setdefault(c, {})[i] = v
    out.setdefault(i, {})[c] = v
df = pd.DataFrame(out)[[0,1,2]].sort_index()
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2
0  NaN  2.0  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  2.0
2  1.0  2.0  NaN
```

Note that this outcome is different from yours but it appears your expected outcome has a mistake because for `MovieID`s `1` and `2`, `userID`s `2` and `3` both rate them, so the value of the corresponding cell should be `2` not `0`.